# Dynamic form choices not being displayed: DJANGO

Tags: python, django

I am trying to dynamically add form choices based on a session variable.

I have a views.py with a choice form that redirects to my second form (which isn't displaying my choices)

views.py:

```
def teacher(request):

  if request.method == 'GET':
      form = TeacherForm()

  else:
      form = TeacherForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          date_list = []
          if form.cleaned_data['teacher'] == 'No Preference':
              for i in Availability.objects.all():
                  date_list.append(str(i.dates))
              request.session['choices'] = tuple(date_list)

      return redirect('book-appt')

  context = {
      'form': form,
  }

  return render(request, 'main/booktchr.html', context)
```

after successful submission of the above view user is sent to another view with another form. On that second view, in the following form's **init** I try to populate the choices with the stores in the session variable above.

forms.py:

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):

   def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
      super (BookingForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
      self.fields['booking_date'].choices = request.session['choices']


   booking_date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

However the form is rendered and the choicefield is empty. Any help is much appreciated.

I'm not entirely sure this is the best way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve so any other methods are welcome, basically what I am trying to do is set the `booking_date` choices dynamically based on what is set in the `request.session['choices']` variable in the view.

thanks

**EDIT: Got it working. Had to change my views.py to the following:**

```
def teacher(request):

  if request.method == 'GET':
      form = TeacherForm()

  else:
      form = TeacherForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          date_list = [("", "date")]
          if form.cleaned_data['teacher'] == 'No Preference':
              for i in Availability.objects.all():
                  date_list.append((str(i.user), str(i.dates)))
              request.session['choices'] = date_list

      return redirect('book-appt')

  context = {
      'form': form,
  }

  return render(request, 'main/booktchr.html', context)
```

and changing my field on the form to `booking_date = forms.ChoiceField()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by editing my views.py to the following:

```
 def teacher(request):

  if request.method == 'GET':
      form = TeacherForm()

  else:
      form = TeacherForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          date_list = [("", "date")]
          if form.cleaned_data['teacher'] == 'No Preference':
              for i in Availability.objects.all():
                  date_list.append((str(i.user), str(i.dates)))
              request.session['choices'] = date_list

      return redirect('book-appt')

  context = {
      'form': form,
  }

  return render(request, 'main/booktchr.html', context)
```

and changing my field on the form to `booking_date = forms.ChoiceField()`

Answer (score 0):

The Django Form properties are static properties of the class, this means you can't set them dynamically (they are evaluated when the class is declared, not at runtime, this is why the choices are empty).   :)

I think the best way to get what you want is to render the form manually (eg: `{% for choice in choices %}`), use a TextField as the form property and validate the input with the method `clean_choices()` of the form class: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: Hey, you can set the choices dynamically by using the __init__ method in the form. I think my error was being caused by not saving data in the correct format when saving it in the view. You can see my updated post for how I solved it. Thank you